# How to read "string" from command line argument in C?

Tags: c

I've a question about passing in parameters via the command line.

My `main()` looks like

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){
  int b, d, n, flag;  
  char *init_d, tst_dir[100];

  argv++;
  init_d=*(argv++);
  //printf(); <--------What do I have to do to init_d so that I can print it later?
```

If `argv` is a pointer to an array of pointers I'm assigning `init_d` to point to the value being pointed to by the pointer `argv` points to? (If that even makes sense)

I assume I have to get that value into a character array in order to print it out but if I don't know the size of the "string" I am passing in, I am not sure how to achieve this.
For instance if i run my code './myprogram hello' compared to './myprogram alongerinput'

Comment: Okay thanks everybody I apologize for my stupidity I kept getting segmentation faults but I see why now.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can print the arguments without transferring them into character arrays. They are null-terminated C strings and `printf` eats them for breakfast:

```
for (i=0; i<argc; i++)
  printf("%s\n", argv[i]);
```

Comment: Well I don't want to print the arguments right away, I need to store the value passed in a variable which I want to print later in a function

Comment: @mike OK, save them away. The OS allocates the space for `argv` and since your entire program is contained inside `main` and whatever it calls, the memory will be valid for the duration.

Comment: usually we'd want to print from `argv[1]` onwards as `argv[0]` is the name of the program if I read the Kerrigan book correctly just now.

Answer (score 6):

Here is example that converts command line arguments to single string:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc < 1)
        return 0;

    int i;
    int strsize = 0;
    for (i=1; i<argc; i++) {
        strsize += strlen(argv[i]);
        if (argc > i+1)
            strsize++;
    }

    printf("strsize: %d\n", strsize);

    char *cmdstring;
    cmdstring = malloc(strsize);
    cmdstring[0] = '\0';

    for (i=1; i<argc; i++) {
        strcat(cmdstring, argv[i]);
        if (argc > i+1)
            strcat(cmdstring, " ");
    }

    printf("cmdstring: %s\n", cmdstring);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`argv` is a pointer to an array of null-terminated strings. You do not need to know the size of the string; all you need to do is point to the value since the end of the string is indicated with a '\0'.

```
char* init_d = argv[0];
printf("%s", init_d);
```

If you did want to know the length of the string you could use `strlen(argv[0])`.

Answer (score 3):

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){ 

    while(--argc>0)
       printf("%s\n",*++argv);
    return 0;
}

argc: argument count i.e. number of arguments in command line
argv: argument vector
```

if your program is `myProg` then `myProg hello` in command line has argc=2 (including program name), argv[0] is "myProg", and argv[1] is "hello"

Answer (score 2):

After running

```
init_d = *(argv++);
```

(parens not necessary, btw), init_d is a pointer to a character.  In C, a string is a character pointer that adheres to the contract that if it is advanced far enough, eventually a null character ('\0') will be reached, signifying the end of the string.  In other words, init_d is now precisely the string you want.  You can print it with

```
printf("%s", init_d);
```

Note, btw, that *argv++ is giving you the first element of argv, which is actually the name of the function on the command line.  You probably want the first command line argument, which you'll get with *++argv.

Comment: You missed his `argv++;` which already skips the command name.

Answer (score 0):

You can output the string you pointing with init_d at with

```
printf("%s", init_d);
```

"%s" output all characters of the string until it reach a '\0'. In C, strings are null terminated.