# C - Command line arguments as strings?

Tags: c, command-line

So I'm confused on how exactly command line arguments work in C... so I have these command line arguments that I'm giving:

```
 ./myclient1 MyPCName 12 7894
```

So I want to read `argv[2] (12)`  as a String... but I'm confused exactly how values are stored in the command line. I looked at both [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5046035/how-to-read-string-from-command-line-argument-in-c) SO post,[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796662/how-to-take-integers-as-command-line-arguments) this [link](http://faculty.cs.niu.edu/~mcmahon/CS241/Notes/command_line_args.html) but I'm still confused... what is the data type of `argv[2]`? Is it an integer? Or are all command line arguments originally strings? So `argv[2]` is actually:

```
  argv: 
  [0]
  [1]
  [2] --> 1 | 2 | \0
```

I'm just really confused.... currently, I just converted to an integer using `atoi()` and then converted back to a string using `snprintf`, but it's not working correctly and I'm wondering if I need to do this at all.

I'm new to C so any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!!

[edit]

this is what I had done before:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 clientID = atoi(argv[2]);
snprintf(clibuff,300,"%d",clientID);  //now clibuff has the value of 
                                      //clientID in a string.
}
```

Comment: Please post some code of what you've tried.

Comment: All command line arguments come in as strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A hosted C implementation (such as you surely are using) permits exactly two signatures for `main()`, and if you want access to the command line arguments then only one will do:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]);
```

You can spell it in couple of other, equivalent ways, but I prefer that one because it emphasizes the array nature of `argv`.  Each element, of course, points to one of the first character of a standard C string containing the corresponding command-line argument.  Thus, the type of `argv[2]` is always `char *`, and you don't need to do anything special to handle it as a C string.

Comment: thanks... I think this answer made things much more clearer.

Answer (score 3):

Command line arguments are stored as an array of zero-terminated strings.

So to answer your question, the type of `argv[2]` is `char *`

The type of `argv` is `char **`

Comment: Oh... thanks I see. So then my understanding was largely correct. So then `12` is stored as a string with an array of `char`....

Answer (score 2):

Here are some great explanations on CLI arguments:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_command_line_arguments.htm

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/A_Little_C_Primer/C_Command_Line_Arguments

Answer (score 1):

a copy of your test code would be useful..

I usually declare argv this way:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv);
```

When the program starts, the arguments to main will have been initialized to this:

- argc is greater than zero.
- argv[argc] is a null pointer.
- argv[0] to argv[argc-1] are pointers to strings
- argv[0] will be a string containing the program's name or a null string if that is not available. 
  Remaining elements of argv represent the arguments supplied to the program.

This Testprogram should work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        while(argc--)
                printf("%s\n", *argv++);
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The argv[0] is always the name of your program, and yes all your arguments are string you should count your arguments since the argv[1].